# Drawing $(x_n,y_n) = \left((1+\frac{1}{5}(-1)^n)\cos n\theta,(1+\frac{1}{5}(-1)^n)\sin n\theta\right)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I have a problem where I am given this function:

$$\begin{cases}
x_n = (1+\frac{1}{5}(-1)^n)\cos n\theta \\
y_n = (1+\frac{1}{5}(-1)^n)\sin n\theta
\end{cases}$$

if $\theta=\frac{\pi}{5}$ , how should I draw this function $p(x_n,y_n)$?
thank you in advence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both $x_n$ and $y_n$ are periodic you only need to plot the first $10$ points $P(x_n,y_n)$.

Since $x_n^2 + y_n ^2= (1\pm 1/5)^2$ your points are alternatively on two circles of radii $6/5$ and $4/5$

Comment: thank you for your help! can you please tell me why you got  $(1±1/5)^2$? i dont understand why disappeared cos and sin.

Comment: When you square both sides you can factor$(1\pm 1/5)^2$ and the trig identity $\sin ^2 x +\cos ^2 x =1$